# SQL Server regularly switching to bad query plan - how to fix

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

SQL Server switches from the good to the bad (or vice versa) around 3 am nightly, which is when the index maintainance is done.
Note that the primary key on TeamLearningPlanObjects is a GUID.

This is the slow plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1uQsgMo9
Notice it starts with the EventTraining and Courses table, does NOT use the table variable. So it's not using the initial filtering of @TeamPlans.

This is the good plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJ4Iilzo9
This one DOES start with the table variable @TeamPlans

Why would SQL Server occasionally think that NOT using @TeamPlans is a good idea?

I have forced the good plans in the past, and that does appear to work for a while, but then the forced plan goes away. I'm looking at some of the hint options, and there's a lot of complexity there to try to understand.

This is using Microsoft SQL Server 2017.

Comment: What version/edition of sql-server are you using?

Comment: I've encountered similar issues over the years where SQL seems to randomly switch from a good plan to one that resorts to table scans and hash joins. I've never figured out why, so I don't have a proper solution. My workaround has been to add `INNER LOOP JOIN`, `FORCE ORDER`, or `WITH(INDEX(...))` hints after having manually structured the query for efficient sequential execution.  Something you may have already tried. (I've also encountered plans that attempt horribly inefficient parallel operations that I've had to reign in with `OPTION(MAXDOP 1)`, but that doesn't seem to apply here.)

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2017, sorry I didn't include that originally.
Force Order...hmm... sounds promising.

Comment: "...which is when the index maintainance (sic) is done". → "Doctor, it hurts when I do this". Which is to say, have you considered *not* doing the index maintenance?

Comment: Key difference seems to be the estimated rows coming from the table variable in the slow plan is 2 not 1. What is the clustering/primary key of the table variable? Is it `TeamMemberID` or another column?

Comment: It's TeamMemberLearningPlanID. Here's the statement: 
DECLARE @TeamPlans TABLE
(
    TeamMemberLearningPlanID uniqueidentifier INDEX IX1 CLUSTERED,
    TeamLearningPlanID uniqueidentifier,
    TeamMemberID uniqueidentifier,
    TeamID uniqueidentifier
)

Comment: Looks like you need to cluster it on `TeamMemberID` so try `DECLARE @TeamPlans TABLE ( TeamMemberLearningPlanID uniqueidentifier, TeamLearningPlanID uniqueidentifier, TeamMemberID uniqueidentifier INDEX IX1 CLUSTERED, TeamID uniqueidentifier )`. If you can make it (or a combination of columns beginning with `TeamMemberID`) unique then performance should be even better, and then you could just declare it as a primary key.